# Titanium Appcelerator; CommonJS has no method

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, commonjs

I'm pretty new to Appcelerator and I tried to import my own commonJS Library. I followed the instructions on

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium

and created a new file named "logger.js", with the following code:

```
exports.info = function(str) {
  Titanium.API.info(new Date()+': '+str);
};
```

Now I simply try so exceute this code with:

```
var logger = require('logger');
logger.info('TEST TEST TEST');
```

Just like in the example. He found the the file, but didn't recognize my method and I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [602,602] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,602] - In alloy/controllers/index.js:100,12
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,602] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Controller() {
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     function logOutput(str) {
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:         Titanium.API.info(str);
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     }
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     require("alloy/controllers/BaseController").apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     this.__controllerPath = "login";
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     if (arguments[0]) {
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:         __processArg(arguments[0], "__parentSymbol");
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:         __processArg(arguments[0], "$model");
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:         __processArg(arguments[0], "__itemTemplate");
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     }
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     var $ = this;
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     var exports = {};
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     exports.destroy = function() {};
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     _.extend($, $.__views);
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     exports = logOutput;
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     _.extend($, exports);
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: } has no method 'info'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,603] - Source:     logger.info("TEST TEST TEST");
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/index.js:100: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Controller() {
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     function logOutput(str) {
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:         Titanium.API.info(str);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     }
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     require("alloy/controllers/BaseController").apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     this.__controllerPath = "login";
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     if (arguments[0]) {
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:         __processArg(arguments[0], "__parentSymbol");
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:         __processArg(arguments[0], "$model");
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:         __processArg(arguments[0], "__itemTemplate");
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     }
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     var $ = this;
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     var exports = {};
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     exports.destroy = function() {};
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     _.extend($, $.__views);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     exports = logOutput;
[ERROR] :  V8Exception:     _.extend($, exports);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: } has no method 'info'
```

I guess it's so simple but I don't where is my fault.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I got it. The problems were I'm using an "Alloy Project", just like "Alejandro F. Carrera" mentioned it. I simply have to use `Alloy.createController();` to get it work.

```
var logger = Alloy.createController('logger');
logger.info('TEST TEST TEST');
```

now it work.

Thanks to all of you to pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed works for me. Did you create the logger.js in the app/lib directory?

Perhaps you should try to comment out the logger.info(...) line in index.js just to ensure that you are looking at the right problem ;-)

Which version of Titanium Studio are you using? - and on which OS?

/John

Comment: Hi, the file is located under app/controllers. If I uncomment the line logger.info(...) I didn't get any exception.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, Titanium Studio 3.3.0 with Titanium SDK 3.3.0.GA. I added this line `Ti.API.log("Logger: " + logger);` and I can see he finds my file and even outputs my method `...e.info=function(t){Titanium.API.info(new Date+": "+t)}...`.

Comment: Ok, first thing is that these type of CommonJS libraries should go under app/lib as far as I have understood. However, this seems not to be your problem - just a better practice ;-)

Comment: I think something with your project could be wrong. So try this: 1. create a new Alloy project, and preview it (on device or in emulator/Genymotion). 2. Once this works as expected, add your lib and the two lines to index.js. What happens?

Comment: ... and a pointer to another question about placing commonjs: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/150114/titanium-alloy--commonjs-files. By the way, if you haven't already signed up as an Appcelerator Developer I strongly encourage you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is better exports Main Object and access info function (Titanium Good Practices).

logger.js

```
var logger = (function(){

    var self = {};

    self.info = function info(str)
    {
        Ti.API.info(new Date()+': '+str);
    };

    return self;

}());

module.exports = logger;
```

file.js where you need logger

```
var loggerObject = require('logger.js'); // (both files are at the same Path)
loggerObject.info("TEST TEST");
```

I hope my answer helps you ;)

Comment: Hi, sadly I got the same exception :-(.

Comment: Your Project is Alloy type not Mobile Project so you must read this link [Titanium Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers-section-34636384_AlloyControllers-LibraryCodeandCommonJSModules)

Answer (score 0):

Normally we used to put this type of extra functions files under lib directory so you should create one folder and named it lib under app directory and put logger.js file under that folder and try again.

Comment: I did it too, but sadly with the same result :-(